# Laravel: query builder with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with input fields that act as filters. There are values from Orders table and Users table which has a relationship.

e.g.:

```
Order Id     | User Full Name   | Order Price | Date              |

[order filter] [user name filter]               [order date filter]
```

How can I filter a value from a users table via relationship?

This returns error of course:

```
public function name($name)
{
    return $this->builder->where('name', 'LIKE', '%$name%')->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE', '%$name%');
}
```

Error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `orders` where (`name` LIKE %$name% or `surname` LIKE %$name%))
```

Comment: Is your column name `name` or `User Full Name`? Your error message is very clear/simple -> `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause'`. So the column `name` does not exist, so what is the actual column name?

Comment: Your query is now looking for a column 'name' in the orders table, not in the related users table where it probably does exist.
Do you know how to write the query in MySQL?

Comment: @Sean, I know it doesn't exist. I want to search it in users table. Orders table has relationship with it, the question is how to access it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the condition directly to your query builder or create a scope.

Add this to your Order model.

```
public function scopeFilterUser($query, $name)
{
   return $query->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($name) {
       $q->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
           ->orWhere('surname', 'like', "%{$name}%");
   });
}
```

Use it like so

```
$orders = Order::filterUser($name)->get();
```

Apply the condition directly.

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($name) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
        ->orWhere('surname', 'like', "%{$name}%");
})->get();
```

Edit : Based on your filter methods.

```
public function name($name)
{
    return $this->builder->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($name) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', "%{$name}%")
            ->orWhere('surname', 'like', "%{$name}%");
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without adding another filter method? I have one class that does filter for the whole rendered table like here - https://github.com/laracasts/Dedicated-Query-String-Filtering/blob/master/app/LessonFilters.php

Comment: @Rudolph all you had to do was convert the query scope into the filter method. I added it for you. Check my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.